# Problems with relations for group chat in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm creating a Chat app on RoR and I want to make such thing: user can create a chat room and then can invite people to it. I have:

`class Conversation < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :messages, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :creator, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "user_id"
  has_many :users`

But i don't know how to select users that creator is invited to room. So, what i need to do to solve this problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not sure you've fully explained what you want, however by looking at the question, you'd probably need: a **User**, **UserConversation** and a **Conversation** class

```
class UserConversation
  belongs_to :conversation
  belongs_to :user
end

class User
  has_many :user_conversations
  has_many :conversations, through: :user_conversations
end

class Conversation
  has_many :user_conversations
  belongs_to :creator, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "user_id"
  has_many :users, through: :user_conversations
end
```

To select the users, you'd end up with something like:

```
conversation.users
```

With this basic setup,

1. A user can create a group chat/conversation
2. A user can add/assign other users to the group chat
3. A user can participate in multiple group chats
4. If there are other settings that should be done with the user within a conversation, it could be done on the user_conversation e.g. say for each chat, I want to use different user names or other config like that.

Comment: Thanks, that's what i need.